# Do you use the plural or singular when asking for a comparison?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

On a web page form the following question is asked:

"Are your business and home address the same?*"

Is this correct? I am often wrong about stuff like this but shouldn't it be:

"Are your business and home addresses the same?"
Or
"Is your business and home address the same?"

Comment: I think both are fine. I might be a bit more inclined to use singular if I'm actually *expecting* them to be "the same" (since by implication there's actually only one "address"). In contexts where I *know* there are two *("Have you filled in your business and home addresses/phone numbers on the application form?")* I'd be much more likely to use plural. But the *verb* would always be ***are***, not ***is***.

Comment: What a web site. A fine analysis of a pretty complex issue is given as a 'comment' by a person nearing their century. And on the other hand ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were asked to choose between "Are your business and home addresses the same?" and "Is your business and home address the same?" I would probably choose the former because the logic of expanded question "Are your business and home addresses the same [as each other]?" seems better suited to handling both affirmative and negative answers gracefully than does the logic of the expanded question "Is your business and home address the same [as itself]?"—and easier for the site user to arrive at than the logically stronger but inferentially more difficult expansion "Is your business [address] and [your] home address [one and] the same?"

However, if I were copyediting  the web page form in question, I wouldn't use either of those wordings. Instead, I would frame the question like this:

> Is your business address the same as your home address?

This wording explicitly identifies what is being compared to what, with no implicit "expanded logical form" lurking in the background. A person reading the question won't spend any time at all wondering whether there's something screwy about the subject/verb agreement or about way the comparison is made.

All too often writers force themselves to consider choices in an entirely artificial either/or world in which neither choice is entirely to their liking. I recommend breaking free of those kinds of choices, on the theory that if both options are unsettling or otherwise unsatisfactory to you, they may be so to your readers as well. Look further, and you may find a better option that no one would object to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct, since the conjunction of two singular noun phrases which refer to different things is plural.  Here, "your business (address)" and "(your) home address" are the singular noun phrases which are conjoined.

Comment: I wouldn't say those things, either.  But neither of your examples appears to be a conjunction of two singular noun phrases, so the relevance is not obvious.

Comment: The key point here is 'are they being considered as referring to different things?' OP's example is tricky, as FF points out, because the questioner may have the idea that they probably are the same (and probably choose 'address') **or** the idea that they probably differ (and naturally be swayed towards 'addresses'). Thus, saying one alternative is right is not the best answer. Also, have you noticed that you've said 'Yes' to '_"Are your business and home address the same?*":

Is this correct? '_ ?

Comment: In your phrasing of "the key point" are you using "they" to refer to the two singular noun phrases of the rule I suggested?  I look at your examples, and I don't see two noun phrases.  Where are they?

Comment: ......You first.

Comment: On your last question, yes, that example sentence sounds okay, perhaps because I have just one address which serves as both home and business address.

Comment: The snag with 'counting noun phrases' where _and_ is used as a coordinator is that it is senseless to regard identical structures as unitary or duplex without regard to the notional cohesiveness or disjointness. Thus _Bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast_ (unitary in concept, perhaps even a three-word compound noun) but _Bacon and eggs are both cheaper than they used to be_. 'Rules' are almost always really 'guidelines'.

Comment: When you count noun phrases in your example "bacon and eggs", how many do you come up with?  I see two nouns.

Comment: Firstly, I see two examples. // Obviously, the surface structure is two noun phrases coordinated by and in each case. But they take different forms of the verb. See [A Communicative Grammar of English
 By Geoffrey Leech, Jan Svartvik](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EtYWAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT293&lpg=PT293&dq=coordinated+noun+phrases+singular&source=bl&ots=J6IOnaMQgE&sig=pCkgvYR8xfnw0lTQ5GwJvxX9uII&hl=en&sa=X&ei=64fBVNG3Nszy7AaS1oDADQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=coordinated%20noun%20phrases%20singular&f=false) Section 512.

Comment: You mean it's obvious that that "bacon and eggs" is two coordinated noun phrases?  How is that obvious?  "bacon" is a noun, isn't it?  "eggs" is a noun, isn't it?  In general, you can coordinate two constituents of the same category to create a constituent of that same category, can't you?

Comment: You're playing with semantics. The **string** _bacon and eggs_ is usually afforded singular or plural agreement depending on whether the speaker etc has one meal (unitary) or two commodities (disjoint) in mind. This is notional agreement. FumbleFingers has already given the correct answer here.

Comment: No, I'm playing with syntax.  I don't do semantics.  Are you using what you think speakers have in mind as evidence? How do you know what is in minds?  This sort of thing is what has given semantics a bad name.

Comment: Here are two contradictory usages, which shows why I'm not counting your 'noun phrases' [bolding mine]:

‘A singular verb is also sometimes seen when … **two coordinated noun phrases** refer to one concept: _Law and order was very harsh in medieval England_.’
{[A Concise Contrasted Grammar … L Hjulmand](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5NzIskfST1IC&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq="coordinated+noun+phrases"&source=bl&ots=7R5v3Ic472&sig=8wAiVjY6D3dKX7MarxOgECeqlgk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AeDCVMirKeey7Qbl74CwDQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22coordinated%20noun%20phrases%22&f=false)} . . .

Comment: ' ... in the **coordinated noun phrase** _Tom and Mary_ ...' [Wikipedia]. Whether one calls it a coordinated noun phrase or two coordinated noun phrases, what determines the form of the following verb is _is the whole referring to a single concept or not?_ .

Comment: Ahem.  What is the difference between a noun and a noun phrase?  Do you have an idea about that?  (My view is largely derived from McCawley's discussions in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.)

Comment: At last, you've conceded that you have a particular (though not universally accepted) view. I'm not interested in arguing about which terminology is 'correct'. I fully endorse FumbleFingers' answer (as a 'comment'), as others here seem to (5 upvotes). He wisely steers clear of ambiguous terminology.